# Object index inside for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, mongoose

I have the following problem using javascript (using node.js and mongoose):
I have 2 objects, the first `object_1 = {"title": "Equipment 1", "description": "My equipment 1"}` and the second `object_2 = {"title": "Equipment 2", "description": "My gear 2"}`.
The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to overwrite my second object with the information from the first, and I'm using the following code for this:

```
for (let i in object_1) {
    object_2.i = object_1.i;
}
```

And the problem I see happening, is that the index variable "i" inside the loop is not being "attached" when I search for `object_2.i` and `object_1.i`.

I tested it outside the loop and my code works very well, I would like to know how I use this 'for' loop index in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're question is. Are you aware of the `Object.assign` function?

Comment: Oh my God, I didn't know him, he worked perfectly for me! Thank you very much!
I'm already using this command that passed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is the real answer, but I also wanted to point out that another way to attain your desired functionality is to use `Object.assign`, which is supported by more browsers as compared to the spread operator (`...`):

```js
Object.assign(object_1, object_2);
```

Comment: yes, I didn't know this command, it worked perfectly for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `i` inside the loop returns `"object_index"` as a string. What you're doing in this code is `object_2."title" = object_1."title"` which will fail because you can't access the key inside an object like this. You have to use it like `object_1[i] = object_2[i]` and it should work. One other way of handling this is `object_1 = {...object_1, ...object_2}` without having to do a for loop.

Comment: it worked for me too! I ended up choosing to use the Object.assign() command. Thank you!